# How can I read nested structure in my code?

Tags: c++, oop, nested

I'm trying to create a struct, which has a nested struct inside of it (sub-struct). How can I define such a sub-struct, and how can I access it from outside?

Here are my structs:

```
    struct Uniform
        {
           std::string color;
        };

    struct Team
    {
        std::string tname;
        int poensHome;
        int poensGuest;
        Uniform teamUniform;

    };

    struct Player
    {
        std::string name;
        std::string surname;
        int goals;
        Team* team;
    };
```

Here is the function that should read the values into a team, how can I read the value of the nested structure Uniform uniformTeam?

```
   void read1(Team a[],int n)    
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cout<<endl<<"Name of the team:";
            cin>>a[i].tname;
            cout<<endl<<"Poens of the team (home):";
            cin>>a[i].poensHome;
            cout<<endl<<"Poens of the team(guest)";
            cin>>a[i].poensGuest;


        }
    }
```

Do I read it by:

```
    cout<<endl<<"color  of the team uniform";
    cin>>a[i].Uniform.teamUniform;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no nested struct in your example. You declared a struct and used it in another struct. A nested struct is

```
struct A { 
    struct B {};
};
```

You have

```
struct A{};
struct B {
    A a;
};
```

You can write with

```
cin>>a[i].teamUniform.color;
```

There is nothing special.

You could nest your structures

```
struct Player
{
    struct Team
    {
        struct Uniform
        {
           std::string color;
        };
        std::string tname;
        int poensHome;
        int poensGuest;
        Uniform teamUniform;

    };
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    int goals;
    Team* team;
};
```

but I think you confuse something. Probably it's not what you really want.

You can declare a struct and declare a member in the same step:

```
struct Player
{
    struct Team
    {
        struct Uniform
        {
           std::string color;
        } teamUniform;
        std::string tname;
        int poensHome;
        int poensGuest;
    }* team;
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    int goals;
};
```

In that case the structs can be anonymous:

```
struct Player
{
    struct
    {
        struct
        {
           std::string color;
        } teamUniform;
        std::string tname;
        int poensHome;
        int poensGuest;
    }* team;
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    int goals;
};
```

Comment: How can I make a nested stucture in this code then? I thought it was correct.

Comment: @Klea Why do you want to use a nested structure?

Comment: Because that's what I need to. I have to use nested structure too for my assignment.

Comment: @Klea Are you sure it's not just a bad word choice from your teacher? Your approach is fine (and readable), nested structures are only useful for very deep encapsulation.

Comment: I know, but we have to include nested structure too. @Yksisarvinen

Answer (score 0):

Read it the same way you read any structure member, there's nothing special about nested structures (apart from the nesting).

```
cout<<endl<<"color  of the team uniform";
cin>>a[i].teamUniform.color;
```